# Macro's Cell Value isn't effecting sheet

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I'm writing a macro to concatenate a few columns into another column for a sheet that will eventually have thousands of rows. For the sake of testing I'm using four rows of data. My issue is that the Cells(i,25).Value is not populating when I run the following code. The code isn't breaking and I'm not getting any error messages. I tried assigning a 2 to column 26 using Cells(i,26) and that wasn't working either.

```
Sub concat()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim add As String
 i = 1
 
 Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
  add = Cells(i, 14).Value
  Cells(i, 25).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Cells(i, 2).Value & " " & Left(add, 3)
  i = i + 1
 Loop
End Sub
```

Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Best to qualify what `Worksheet` and `Workbook` these `Cells` are on/in.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you change the code a little. I have used the `IsEmpty` command before and it's not the most suitable one for this.

```
Sub concat()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim add As String
 Dim last_1 As Long
 Dim last_2 As Long
 Dim last_14 As Long
 Dim lastCell As Long

 last_1 = Sheets("test3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 last_2 = Sheets("test3").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
 last_14 = Sheets("test3").Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row
 lastCell = WorksheetFunction.Max(last_1 , last_2, last_14)

 For i = 1 To lastCell
   add = Sheets("test3").Cells(i, 14).Value
   Sheets("test3").Cells(i, 25).Value = Sheets("test3").Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & Sheets("test3").Cells(i, 2).Value & " " & Left(add, 3)
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Unfortunately this still isn't effecting my sheet at all and populating the last column

Comment: Okay, What is your sheet name?

Comment: My sheet name is "test3"

Comment: I defined my sheet and workbook, I discovered I hadn't saved the workbook properly. Thanks for your code recomendations!